# Json and requests in python

Tags: python, json

```
import requests
import json

url = 'mywebsite/test.php'
myobj = data = {"username" : "test", "password" : "1234"}


myobj = json.dumps(myobj)
x = requests.post("loginUser",url, data = myobj)

print(x)
```

I get the  following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 55, in <module> x = requests.post("loginUser",url, data = myobj) TypeError: post() got multiple values for argument 'data'
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The call signature is [`requests.post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post). You use "loginUser" as the url, and your url as data, so double data. What is your intent for "loginUser"? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It is the method I am trying to call in my php script I am connecting to

Comment: That will depend on how your test.php is written. My guess is that `requests.post(url, data = myobj)` will work - assuming that your test.php hard codes the call to `loginUser`.

Comment: This is my php code:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/10141PTCmEFwC9_fkRbw8asP3-eU1fIjR99lnni6mxdU/edit

Comment: I am so sorry but I just figured out that I used the wrong terminology when saying that loginUser was a method. I should have said it was a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it. Problem was that I didn’t put http:// in front of the url and I didn’t format my JSON request the way my php was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs:

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/

```
requests.post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs)[source]
Sends a POST request.

Parameters: 
url – URL for the new Request object.
data – (optional) Dictionary, list of tuples, bytes, or file-like object to send in the body of the Request.
json – (optional) json data to send in the body of the Request.
**kwargs – Optional arguments that request takes.
Returns:    
Response object
```

and so your command should be:

```py
myobj = json.dumps(myobj).encode("ascii")
x = requests.post(url = url, data = myobj)
```

or without using json.dumps:

```py
x = requests.post(url = url, json = myobj)
```

What exactly is "loginUser" for in this case? is that a URI route, field, or parameter?

Comment: "loginUser" is the function in my php script that i want to send the data to

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning python myself and have used requests a bit.

I've always put the url at the beggining and payload at the end:
i.e Should `"LoginUser"` go at the end?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).